# .htaccess doesn't redirect to error page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, error-handling

I want my page to redirect to custom error 500 page. However, when I specify the page I want to be redirected to, the plain old 500 error page appears, and not mine.

I'm using this line to do it

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/error500.html
```

However if I specify HTML instead of the link, it works

```
ErrorDocument 500 '<div style="width:200px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center">Oooppss <br></div>'
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work. It displays the path string in plain text.

Comment: What is your RewriteBase base ?  can you try complete path /usr/local/web/index.html ?

Comment: Yes it works with the full server path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your RewriteBase base ?

can you try complete path /usr/local/web/index.html ?

~K

Answer (score 0):

Set RewriteBase:

```
RewriteBase /
```

And make sure that the file `/errors/error500.html` exists.